# Most efficient order of learning all the Romance languages?

Tags: romance-languages, learning-order

If someone aimed to learn *all* of the six biggest Romance languages - **Catalan**, **French**, **Italian**, **Portuguese**, **Romanian**, **Spanish** - is there a good line of reasoning for which order to learn them?

I found [this article](http://lingwall.org/wp/?p=10), which suggests an order of:

1. **Spanish** and **French**, in either order - these have the most and best learning materials
2. **Italian**
3. **Catalan** - little material, but it's in between Spanish and Italian, which you now already know.
4. **Portuguese** - easier after learning Spanish
5. **Romanian** - the most different and most difficult

What order is the most efficient for learning all the languages?

Comment: I have seen several resources about this and I doubt that people can reach an agreement about this. This looks more like a question for a discussion forum.

Comment: I think it is a valid question, even though it is very difficult to answer based on experience or research. But difficult questions are acceptable on SE. One just needs to be even more careful about downvoting or deleting bad answers and non-answers.

Comment: I am voting to close this question because the sequence of learning languages is really opinion-based.

Comment: I disagree and think that someone who has learned all (or at least most) of them could provide a logical point of view.